# Gradle: Dependency insight report cannot be generated because the input configuration was not specified

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to resolve dependency conflict in my gradle applicaiton. My top-level build.gradle is:

```
archivesBaseName = 'message-sender-rest'

apply plugin: 'paas-publish'

dependencies {

    compile(project(':message-sender-api'))

    compile(libraries.springBoot)
    compile(libraries.loggingRuntime)

    compile(libraries.integration)

    compile(libraries.serviceFrameworkServer)
    compile(libraries.serviceFrameworkApp)
    compile(libraries.serviceFrameworkSpringIntegration)

    testCompile(libraries.testing)
    testCompile(libraries.springTest)

    testCompile(libraries.activeMqBroker)
}
```

When I try to run `gradle dependencyInsight --configuration compile`, I get the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Configuration with name 'compile' not found.
```

There is a whole bunch of lower level gradle files, but I guess that should just work using the top-level one, isn't it?

When i just try `gradle dependencies`, it returns pretty much nothing:

```
gradle dependencies
dockerBuild tag: dev.docker.orbitbenefits.capita/orbit/message-sender-rest:bOD-9656-ConfigServer-n0
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

No configurations

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Any idea what I may be missing?

Comment: I don't believe that error message corresponds to that command.  You are not passing any `--configuraion` flag (note the misspelling).

Comment: I do - please see edit in the post. Sorry for the typo

Comment: The error message still shows a typo.  So i suspect that you have a typo in your command too.

Comment: Yes, you're right - that was a typo. The actual problem is different from what I've put in my initial post. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was not specifying the module I wanted to inspect:
The project had a sub-project (`module message-sender-server`). Specifying the module name actually worked:

`gradlew message-sender-server:dependencyInsight --dependency webmvc`

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to add a configuration like so:

`gradlew message-sender-server:dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency webmvc`

Comment: Perhaps your dependency was specific to the `compile` configuration of your project? Although I don't see how narrowing the scope would find the dependency not found with broader scope. Anyway, that's a good tip too - to seek for a dependency for a specific scope. +1 from me!